Incorporating google sheets function into macro
In Google Sheets, I can retrieve an exchange rate by typing this formula into a cell
=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPUSD")
I would like to use this function in an apps script, but I don't know how to use this function and assign the result to a variable.
Any ideas?
I tried
var response = GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPUSD");
but that failed
